# How to output IP address to file with powershell "Write-Output" command without null values

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write an IP address (It's just a random test IP I used) to a file using powershell's `Write-Output` and it's writing the IP address to the file but adding null values after every character. Is there any way to do this properly, **without the null characters**?

[image]

Comment: Try `'10.0.0.24' | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -Append aws_hosts`.

Comment: as n0rd implied, that looks like a two-byte character set shown in a display that only knows about one-byte chars. [*grin*] make sure you save the data with the _expected_ character encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but `Write-Output '10.0.0.24' >> aws_hosts` seem to produce an UTF-16 file (with at least 2 bytes per character) and then your VS Code tries to interpret it as UTF-8 showing all those `\0` paddings as characters of its own.

Try `'10.0.0.24' | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -Append aws_hosts` instead. That allows to control the output encoding.